# How to repair GDB_ITEMS.Definition if fields are missing (GPFieldInfoEx)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, file-geodatabase-api

I read file geodatabase schema of all feature classes by parsing Definition field XML-s from GDB_Items table. I am using ESRI File GDB API. It's main XML element (for feature class) is DEFeatureClassInfo and then under GPFieldInfoExs element information about each field is stored in GPFieldInfoEx element. Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEFeatureClassInfo xsi:type="typens:DEFeatureClassInfo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.3">
  <CatalogPath>\Constructed_Features\Constructed_Feature_pt</CatalogPath>
  <Name>Constructed_Feature_pt</Name>
  <ChildrenExpanded>false</ChildrenExpanded>
  <DatasetType>esriDTFeatureClass</DatasetType>
  <DSID>67</DSID>
  <Versioned>false</Versioned>
  <CanVersion>false</CanVersion>
  <ConfigurationKeyword></ConfigurationKeyword>
  <RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>10.0</RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>
  <HasOID>true</HasOID>
  <OIDFieldName>OBJECTID</OIDFieldName>
  <GPFieldInfoExs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfGPFieldInfoEx">
    <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
      <Name>OBJECTID</Name>
      <AliasName>OBJECTID</AliasName>
      <ModelName>OBJECTID</ModelName>
      <FieldType>esriFieldTypeOID</FieldType>
      <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
      <Required>true</Required>
      <Editable>false</Editable>
    </GPFieldInfoEx>
    <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
      <Name>Shape</Name>
      <AliasName>Shape</AliasName>
      <ModelName>Shape</ModelName>
      <FieldType>esriFieldTypeGeometry</FieldType>
      <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
      <Required>true</Required>
    </GPFieldInfoEx>
...etc.
```

However for some file GDBs, upgraded from 9.3 version to 10.3, not all fields are listed (under own GPFieldInfoEx element), I see only part of them.

**Do you know a way how to repair such file GDBs so definitions include all tables fields?**

I tried to add new fields; they are appended, but those missing fields still do not appear.

I also tried to create new file GDB using ArcCatalog 10.3; field edits appear under GPFieldInfoExs correctly.

EDIT: Also tried to export full gdb to XML workspace document with data and import to empty gdb but this did not help.

Comment: Have you tried updating metadata for the table whose fields are missing? Maybe that also synchronizes the definition.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall What do you mean by "update metadata". How to update it?

Comment: Maybe the more appropriate term is "upgrade".  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/metadata/upgrading-existing-fgdc-metadata-from-the-description-tab.htm

Comment: Updated or upgraded... no luck.

Answer (score 2):

try this method,I hope It would be helpful and probably solve your problem, 
The [Recover File Geodatabase tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/recover-file-geodatabase.htm) can only recover simple feature classes and tables. Complex data and relationships will not be recovered, Furthermore there is another tools [X-Ray](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ea218ff575f4a5195e01a2cae03a0ae) sometime you can get help from that for some geodatabase problem or do some changes in database design.

Comment: RecoverFileGDB_management "flattened" feature classes by dropping feature datasets, but did not solve fields metadata problem.