# recover corrupted file geodatabase (corruption after adding a new field)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

I was trying to add a field in one of the feature class of my file geodatabase, but there was a small network failure and the operation corrupted my feature class.

I would like to recover this fgdb, in particular the field information which is unique. I've tried with "RecoverFileGDB_management (input_file_gdb, output_location, out_name)" as suggested in [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210125/how-to-repair-gdb-items-definition-if-fields-are-missing-gpfieldinfoex/210584#210584), but it did not work for the corrupted featre class (only the feature classes that I did not touch were recovered).

The feature class is a "simple" polygon FC, but it is quite large (10^6 records and 80 fields). If I can get the information from the table, I am already happy, because I have a backup of the geometry but not for all the fields of the table.

Comment: Which other question (please always provide links to any questions you mention) suggested you try RecoverFileGDB_management ()?

Comment: Try next to export to xml recordset document and then import said recordset document into your recovered database, that's the next level of desperation. Please try to avoid modifying geodatabases (personal or file) over a network, even editing over a network is prone to causing corruption. Enterprise databases are much more robust. If you must have your database on a networked computer consider implementing the workflow of initiating a remote desktop connection or create a backup before changing if RDP isn't allowed.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for the advice. I usually do work on a local copy, but I was in a hurry and this gdb was quite large, so I thought that I would save some time... Murphy's law...

Comment: @MichaelStimson the xml export failed, but this was an interesting suggestion. Maybe it could help someone else. I've noticed that ArcGIS created a _temp file with about half of the size of the the original file (in my backup version before a few changes) so I guess that the data is definitely lost.

Comment: This most likely won't work but you might see if QGIS can open the problem feature class.

Comment: @johns good idea, but I think that the data is definitely lost....

Comment: You have my deepest sympathy.... I've been in this pit of despair *many* times before. If export to XML workspace/recordset fails then it's time to abandon hope. Is there no chance the data was part of a regular backup server side?